# How Can I Design a Very Simple HTML Page?

Tags: html

The image posted below is taken from a word document. I need create a similar one in HTML. Which tags should i use to help structure same way you see it below. Discard the fonts/colors tags.

[image]

Comment: Use OpenOffice or Word, design it and then save as an HTML page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As James Black said, MS Word or Open office can save the document as an html file automatically for you. From file save as and then choose web page.

Anyway if you want to do it manually then it isn't a single tag that you'll end up using. I just did a quick mock up for you which closely resembles your image.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Invoice Title</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="main">
        <div id="header">
            <div>Shipment # </div>
            <div>Invoice # </div>
            <div><h2>CUSTOMER PO </h2></div>
        </div>

        <div id="content">
                <div style="text-align:center;" ><h1>PACKAGING LIST </h1> </div>
                <div style="padding-top:50px;"><h2>Motion detectors consisting of the following,</h2> </div>
                    <div id="items" style="padding-top:40px;"> 1. P/N Auro</div>

        </div>

        <div id="footer">
                 <div id="items" style="padding-top:200px;"><strong> Distributor</strong></div>
        </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 3):

http://www.w3schools.com/
Just learn some basic tags, maybe some CSS if you want to make it pretty.